Incorrect styling in React-Markdown and NextJS
In my NextJS app, there is one component that I use to display some Markdown text returned by Ollama. I use react-markdown to parse the texts and render HTML. However, the rendering result is not as expected. The versions are:

"next": "^14.1.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
"react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
"remark": "^15.0.1",
"remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
"remark-html": "^16.0.1",
"remark-rehype": "^11.1.0",

Shown as the screenshot below, the tags are correct, but headings don't have corresponding font size and weight, ul and ol also have no styles at all. The results are just plain texts. For example, in the screenshot, it shows that headings are using inherit CSS style for both size and weight.

The code of the component is as below.
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import gfm from 'remark-gfm'

export default function MyMarkdown({ children }) {

  return (
    <ReactMarkdown
      remarkPlugins={[gfm]}
    >{children}</ReactMarkdown>
  )
}

And the demo Markdown text I used to test is as below.
`# Demo Markdown Content

## Markdown Elements

### Headings

#### Heading Level 4

##### Heading Level 5

###### Heading Level 6

- Item 1
- Item 2
  - Sub-item 1
  - Sub-item 2
    1. Nested item 1
    2. Nested item 2

[Google](https://www.google.com)

*Italic text* **Bold text**

\`\`\`javascript
function greet(name) {
  console.log(\`Hello, \${name}\`);
}

greet('World');
\`\`\`

> Blockquote

---

\\\*Escaped characters\\\*
`

I tried to use react-markdown, markdown-to-jsx and micromark in my project, but they all show the same problem.
Please point out any mistakes I made and help me to render the Markdown text in this NextJS app correctly.
